# ¿Como comparar dos DataTables?

Tags: c#, sql-server

Que tal tengo este problema, estoy intentando comparar 2 DataTab, este es el codigo que menejo:

```
        DataTable resu = acc.EjecutarSELECT("SELECT Programa, CONCAT(Estilo, ' ', Color) AS Estilo, SUM(Total) AS Pares FROM infolote WHERE (Status = 'NO PAGADO') AND (Autorizado = 1) group by Programa, Estilo, Color");
        DataTable Programa = acc.EjecutarSELECT("SELECT Programa FROM precios_programa");
        foreach (DataRow item in Programa.Rows)
        {                    
                int programa1 = Convert.ToInt32(item["Programa"]);
                int programa2 = Convert.ToInt32(resu.Rows[0]["Programa"]);
                if (programa1 != programa2)
                {
                    acc.EjecutarINSERT("INSERT INTO precios_programa(Programa, Estilo, Pares) VALUES(" + Convert.ToInt32(resu.Rows[0]["Programa"]) + ", '" + resu.Rows[0]["Estilo"] + "', " + Convert.ToInt32(resu.Rows[0]["Pares"]) + ")");
                }                    
        }
```

pero no he podido resolverlo, ya que solo me recorre el datatable de 'programa1', y el de programa2 se queda igual, segun yo, si me tendria que hacer la comparacion bien pero no lo hace

Comment: al usar `resu.Rows[0]` estas tomando el valor siempre de la primer row

Comment: Has pensado en hacer todo en una sola instrucción? `acc.EjecutarINSERT("INSERT INTO precios_programa(Programa, Estilo, Pares) SELECT Programa, CONCAT(Estilo, ' ', Color) AS Estilo, SUM(Total) AS Pares FROM infolote WHERE (Status = 'NO PAGADO') AND (Autorizado = 1) group by Programa, Estilo, Color");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes realizar una busqueda ayudandote con linq para ver si existe en el segundo `datatable` mientras iteras el primero

Algo como esto

```
foreach (DataRow item in Programa.Rows)
{                    
    int programa1 = Convert.ToInt32(item["Programa"]);

    bool exist = resu.AsEnumerable().Any(r=> r.Field<int>("Programa") == programa1);

    if (!exist)
    {
        acc.EjecutarINSERT("INSERT INTO precios_programa(Programa, Estilo, Pares) VALUES(" + Convert.ToInt32(resu.Rows[0]["Programa"]) + ", '" + resu.Rows[0]["Estilo"] + "', " + Convert.ToInt32(resu.Rows[0]["Pares"]) + ")");
    }                    
}
```

[Crear un objeto DataTable a partir de una consulta (LINQ to DataSet)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/creating-a-datatable-from-a-query-linq-to-dataset)

Comment: recomendaria cambies la implementacion de `EjecutarINSERT()` para permitir pasar por parametro una lista de `SqlParameter`